# How to access repeater items from JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a hidden control inside a repeater. How can I access this from JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using JQuery?  This can be easily done by the following:

```
$("#<%= Repeater1.ClientID %>").find("input[type='hidden']")
```

Which scours the entire repeater; because each item doesn't render a wrapper around it (a div or a table, for example), the find does an entire check of the HTML tree.  Otherwise, you'd have to loop through each element, or wrap each item with a DIV, and access the childNodes collection of that DIV, and it would be more of a pain without JQuery, but very possible.

HTH.